# Нахождение аббревиатуры через regexp

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно определить, есть ли в тексте определённая аббревиатура. Например, «СВО!». Но не слово «СВОРА». То есть искомое сочетание не должны окружать другие буквы, но могут любые другие символы (знаки препинания и т.д). Python3.9.

Я придумал нечто такое:
`[^A-zA-ZА-яА-Я]СВО[^A-zA-ZА-яА-Я]`
Но аббревиатуру не находит если это начало / конец или перенос строки. Как это пофиксить?

Comment: `(?<![А-яA-z])СВО(?![А-яA-z])` попробуйте использовать негативный просмотр назад и вперед, либо используйте логическое или: `([^A-zA-ZА-яА-Я]|^)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD: `ёЁ` не входят в диапазон `А-я`, поэтому их следует указывать дополнительно.
Спасибо **Wiktor Stribiżew** за напоминание об этом, а так же верное уточнение по поводу диапазона `А-z` и тому что он не равен `A-Za-z`

---

Для решения подобной задачи можно попробовать использовать группу с логическим или `(...|...)`

```
(^|[^A-Za-zА-яА-ЯёЁ])СВО([^A-Za-zА-яА-ЯёЁ]|$)
```

Так же можно воспользоваться группами с негативным просмотром назад `(?<!...)` и негативным просмотром вперед `(?!...)`

```
(?<![ёЁА-яA-Za-z])СВО(?![ёЁА-яA-Za-z])
```

Так же можно использовать границу слова `\b`, в python она должна работать и с кириллицей на сколько я помню

```
\bСВО\b
```

Comment: Проверьте `А-яА-Я`, кажется, `ёЁА-я` должно быть.